# Adding rows to a DataGridView control causes crash but only on second attempt

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, datagridview

I have a DataGridView (dgvNew) which is populated by a JSON file which is located by a FileSystemWatcher, data is added row by row after being read. It works fine on first file. But if i trigger a new file by copying and pasting the same JSON file it adds the rows again row by row as id expect, but then the whole form crashes with no error.

I've tried TRY..CATCH with WHILE loops for opened the files which works in terms of openning them and adding rows, i just don't understand why it crashes. The code continues to step through regardless even though the form is frozen ? is it Thread related ?

```
    Public Sub subParseJSONs(strFilePath As String, strDesiredField As String)

        Dim json As String
        Dim strMachine As String
        Dim read As New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
        Dim booErrorJSNOArrRead As Boolean
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim dgvIndex As Integer
        Dim booOpened As Boolean
        Dim k As Integer, j As Integer

        booOpened = False
        k = 1
        j = 1
        json = Nothing



        While json Is Nothing
            Try
                j = j + 1
                If j = 10 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("J integer reached 10")
                    Exit While
                    Exit Try
                End If
                json = Replace(Replace(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(strFilePath), vbLf, ""), vbTab, "")
                read = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)

            Catch ex As IOException
                'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
                'GoTo EndOfSUb
            Catch ex As Exception
                'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
                'GoTo EndOfSUb
            Finally
                booOpened = True

            End Try


        End While




        booErrorJSNOArrRead = False
        i = 0


        dgvNew.ColumnCount = 6
        dgvNew.Columns(0).Name = "TempID"
        dgvNew.Columns(1).Name = "DriverName"
        dgvNew.Columns(2).Name = "Seat"
        dgvNew.Columns(3).Name = "RaceTime"
        dgvNew.Columns(4).Name = "ResultTime"
        dgvNew.Columns(5).Name = "CarDriven"


        dgvNew.RefreshEdit()
        dgvNew.Refresh()

        Do Until i = read.Item("Result").Count

            If Not read.Item("Result")(i)("DriverName") = "" Then
                Dim milliseconds As Double = Convert.ToDouble(read.Item("Result")(i)("TotalTime"))
                Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds)

                Dim strMMSSmmm As String = ts.Minutes.ToString & ":" & ts.Seconds.ToString & "." & ts.Milliseconds.ToString

                Dim row As String() = New String() {i + 1,
                                                read.Item("Result")(i)("DriverName"),
                                                read.Item("Result")(i)("DriverName"),
                                                strMMSSmmm,
                                                DateTime.Now, read.Item("Result")(i)("CarModel")}
                dgvNew.Rows.Add(row)

            End If

            i = i + 1

        Loop

        read = Nothing

    End Sub
```

I'm expecting new rows to be added to the bottom of dgvNew, which they are, but then it crashes ?

Comment: How are you calling subParseJSONs?  Those `ex.Message` lines didn't produce anything?

Comment: I think you should 1) Deserialize the JSON in a proper way (possibly, using a class structure). 2) Add the new JSON to a `List(Of class)`. 3) Merge the new List with the existing one if not null. Set the `List(Of class)` as the `DataGridView.DataSource`. If the data needs to be edited, use a BindingList instead.

Comment: Is this `subParseJSONs()` method called from one of the `FileSystemWatcher`'s events? If so then that is usually called in a background thread and will cause issues when you try to access your DGV as it is located on the UI thread. This can be fixed by telling the FSW to invoke its events on the UI thread, by setting the [`FileSystemWatcher.SynchronizedObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to any control on your UI thread, preferably the form it runs in.

Comment: `The code continues to step through regardless even though the form is frozen`, ***don't do work on the UI thread***. Why all of these `Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)`?

Comment: Can you try using json.net with classes and properties? And when you define all the values you just add them to the datagridview.. i could help more if i had the json..